# Accessing a value in beforeInsert event of Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there a way to access value inside the `beforeInsert` event?

For example:

Controller:

```
def save () {
   user = new User(params)
}
```

Domain:

```
String name
String job
String name_and_job

beforeInsert {
  name_and_job = name+job
}
```

In the above `beforeInsert` event I want to get the current `name` and `job` and add those to `name_and_job`. However, this doesn't work.

Please note that this is just an example of the bigger problem I'm working with. Should this type of stuff be done in the controller instead?

Comment: Your save method makes no sense.  You don't call Domain properties statically like that.  If that really is your code, it is no wonder why it does not work.

Comment: Fixed for better explanation.

Comment: I'm just really trying to find out whether I can access actual data for other fields (coming from params) inside the beforeInsert event.

Comment: You should be able to do what you're trying to do.  If it isn't working, maybe you're not giving all the information. What does your actual code look like (assuming you're showing an example)?

Comment: As an FYI, the beforeInsert executes, well, right before the insert. Which means a save call would have had to take place on the Domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller should be like:

```
def save () {
   user = new User(params).save()
}
```

Without the save() call, you just instantiated a transient User object. That's why your `beforeInsert` event never got activated.